# How to convert a List<String> object to String... Object

Tags: java, string

Recently I came across an API and it was using some Parameter

```
void doSomething(final String... olah) {
}
```

I never have seen something like that.

I have a `List<String>` now and I want to call that function with my list of string. How can I achieve that?

Comment: `String...` is equivalent to `String[]`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Welcome to modern Java. That syntax is called `varargs` in Java.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html

You can think of it like

```
void doSomething(final String[] olaf) {

}
```

The only difference is that as the name suggests, it is Variable Length Arguments. You can invoke it with `0` to any number or arguments. Thus, `doSomething("foo")`, `doSomething("foo", "bar")`, `doSomething("foo", "bar", "baz")` are all supported.

In order to invoke this method with a `List` argument though, you'll have to first convert the list into a `String[]`.

Something like this will do:

```
List<String> myList; // Hope you're acquainted with generics?

doSomething(myList.toArray(new String[myList.size()]));
```

Answer (score 3):

`String...` is nothing but `String[]`. So just loop over list and create an array of String and pass that array or more easy way to use [`.toArray(new String[collection.size()])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28T%5b%5d%29) method of Collection class.

Answer (score 2):

String... is the same as String[].

You want to call something like:

```
String[] listArr = list.toArray( new String[ list.size() ] );
doSomething( listArr );
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.toArray(new String[0])`. The [toArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5b%5d%29) method will turn your list of strings (`java.util.List<String>`) into an array of `String` objects.

The '...' syntax is a mechanism to allow a variable number of parameters. You can pass either something like `doSomething("abc", "def", "ghi")` or `doSomething("abc")` or `doSomething(new String[] { "abc", "def", "ghi" })`. The function will see them all as arrays (respectively as length 3, 1 and 3).

Answer (score 1):

See the following to convert List of String to String Array

```
List<String> listOfString = new ArrayList<String>();
        listOfString.add("sunil");
        listOfString.add("sahoo");
        String[] strResult=new String[listOfString.size()];
        strResult =  listOfString.toArray(strResult);
```